# How to use linked objects in boolean modifiers

Tags: python, modifiers, linked-data, boolean-modifier

I have tried linking objects programmatically using the guide [found here](https://youtu.be/tIg-KOeFxkg). This works great also when manipulating objects w.r.t position/pose. When I try to use linked assets in boolean modifiers, it does not work however.

In particular, the modifier gets applied at the original location/pose of the linked object, not at the new position I have put it. Using apply transform does not work, as it will only force-place the asset back to its original position, loosing the  transform.

Is this bug or feature?

How can I use linked assets in boolean modifiers with the proper position/pose?